# confused with method and function binding

Tags: javascript, binding

I've been spending hours just trying to understand function and method binding in javascript. I've seen some articles about "BINDING" on the internet but I can't comprehend them easily. I hope someone could explain it to me more clearly here.
I have this javascript code:

```
function Foo(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

function sayHello() {
    console.log('Hello ' + this.name);
}

var foo = new Foo('Jack');

var substFunc = foo.sayHello.bind(foo);

substFunc();
```

I want the `sayHello()` function to be bound with the `Foo()` so I could use it as a method for displaying "Hello, Jack", but it failed and displayed a message on the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined(...)

Comment: To understand binding you need to understand scope first. Bind basically changes the scope of "this". I would suggest starting from there. :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm just a newbie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close, and your understanding of `Function#bind` was not the issue

`sayHello` is not a property of `foo`, though, it is a global variable, so you can access it like:

```
var substFunc = sayHello.bind(foo);
```

**Snippet:**

```js
function Foo(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

function sayHello() {
    console.log('Hello ' + this.name);
}

var foo = new Foo('Jack');

var substFunc = sayHello.bind(foo);

substFunc();
```

Comment: I feel a bit embarrassed because of that `foo`. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This error's coming up because you're using

```
foo.sayHello
```

...but you never defined that function for foo. sayHello is an independent function. Does that make sense?

Also...an easier way to understand binding is with a simple jquery event binder.

Say you bind your button to trigger a function when you press it. The function is buttonPressed(). Because the button called this function...if you call "this" from the function it's going to refer to the button.

```
$button.on('click', buttonPressed);

function buttonPressed(){
    //this == button
}
```

But if you want to manipulate another element with the "this" variable. You bind that other element instead.

```
$button.on('click', buttonPressed).bind($otherElement);

function buttonPressed(){
    //this == otherElement
}
```

Comment: Great help and tip. Thanks :)

Comment: and by the way, what is that `$otherElement` referring to? Another DOM element like `$('span')` and `$('p')`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, any other element that's not the button :-)

Comment: And I just mentioned, because I use that example a lot, so for me it's a practical application of the bind concept.